# Can there be two vectors U and V in the set of all multiples of vector W, such that the sum of U and V is not there?

Tags: linear-algebra

My intuition says no. But what if W is a zero vector?

Comment: I do not understand what you would like to ask.

Comment: "My intuition says no. But what if W is a zero vector?" is ***not*** a question.

Comment: What are the possible multiples of the zero vector?  For future Questions, please make the body of the Question as self-contained as possible, not relying entirely on the title to bear the burden of stating the problem.  I suspect if you had done a more careful job of stating this problem, it might have lead to your solving it for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there cannot be, because the set of all multiples of some vector is a linear subspace. Thus, if $u,v$ are there, so is $u+v$. This is still true if the vector $w$ is zero, in that case the set of its multiples is still zero, and so are $u,v$.

Comment: We don't need to talk about subspaces here: if $u, v$ are multiples of $w$, then $u=aw$ and $v=bw$ for some scalars $a$ and $b$. But then $u+v=aw+bw=(a+b)w$ is a multiple of $w$ - specifically, by the scalar $a+b$. So we're really using two properties of vector spaces: (1) The field of vectors is closed under addition. (2) Scalar multiplication distributes over vector addition.